# Search and replace text of a certain font

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

I am trying to write a MS Word 2016 VBA macro that searches for certain text in Courier New font and changes it, using .Find and .Execute. It does not work. For some reason it does not set the .Font.Name property as specified. Here is the code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim selRange As Range
    Set selRange = Selection.Range
    With selRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting 
        .Text = "C"
        .Font.Name = "Courier New"
        Debug.Print .Text & " Font: " & .Font.Name
        .Replacement.Text = "G"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Debug.Print .Found
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is the text that is selected:
C C B2 (The first C and B2 are Courier New, the middle C is Arial)

Here is the output:

C Font:

False

Comment: Your code isn't going to find anything because it is missing the line that instructs Find that you want to look for text in a specific font. To get the correct syntax record a macro.

Comment: The line that specifies the font that I want to search for is line 8 in my code. I have tried recording a macro but it does not specify the font name "Courier New". If I specify that I want to search for that font and bold and size 10 then it sets the bold and size attributes but it never seems to set the font name attribute.

Comment: That is strange. I changed the code to Font.NameAscii = "Courier New" and it now works???

Comment: Merely specifying a font name is not enough. The recorded code would also include the vital line `.Format = True`

Comment: That is specified earlier in the code

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Is what you want?

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim selRange As Range
    Set selRange = Selection.Range
    With selRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "C"
        .Font.Name = "Courier New"
        Debug.Print .Text & " Font: " & selRange.Font.Name
        .Replacement.Text = "G"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        Debug.Print .Found
    End With
End Sub
```

If you use **Selection.Range** object and set the argument **Replace:=wdReplaceAll** also,then this two arguments is necessary:

```vb
   , Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
```

and the **selRange** will be changed for every found occurrence.

Here is the output:

**C Font: Courier New**

**True**